# How to update a JSONB object with a parent in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a database with a table `foo` containing a column `id` and a column `data` with the following data:

```
{
   "startDate":"2017-07-04",
   "endDate":"2017-07-10",
   "notDelegated":false,
   "sold":false,
   "disableRanking":false,
   "type":"PERIOD"
}
```

I would like to update this data with a parent `rangeData` and extract the `type` property like this:

```
{
   "rangeData": {
       "startDate":"2017-07-04",
       "endDate":"2017-07-10",
       "notDelegated":false,
       "sold":false,
       "disableRanking":false
   },
   "type":"PERIOD"
}
```

I tried a lot of things with `JSON` operators in vain.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) and delete operator:

```
update foo
set data = jsonb_build_object('rangeData', data- 'type', 'type', data->'type');
```

In the above function call you are creating a json object with two elements:

```
key          value
-------------------------
'rangeData'  data- 'type'   json object 'data' from which the key 'type' was removed
'type'       data->'type'   value of 'type' element of json object 'data'
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/15925/2)

Comment: Great!! You saved my time! Thank you so much ;)

Just for explanation, you could you please explain the content of _jsonb_build_object_? 
The given example in postgresql documentation just indicates that _json_build_object('foo',1,'bar',2)_ gives _{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}_. Your request seems a little bit complex than this simple given example...

Comment: I've added an explanation, hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for this explanation. I didn't know the syntax `data -type`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonb_set(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb[, create_missing boolean])` (see [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html)).

It's not very pretty, but I did this (you can run it yourself on this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/6078/0) I made):

```
SELECT 
  jsonb_set(
    (final.range_data):: jsonb, 
    '{type}', 
    to_jsonb(final.type)
  ) 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      jsonb_set(
        jsonb '{}', '{rangeData}', fields.range_data
      ) AS range_data, 
      fields.type AS type 
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          data.jsonb - 'type' AS range_data, 
          data.jsonb ->> 'type' AS type 
        FROM 
          (
            SELECT 
              '{"startDate":"2017-07-04","endDate":"2017-07-10","notDelegated":false,"sold":false,"disableRanking":false,"type":"PERIOD"}' :: jsonb
          ) data
      ) fields
  ) final;
```

This will get you your jsonb output of:

```
{"rangeData": {"startDate":"2017-07-04","endDate":"2017-07-10","notDelegated":false,"sold":false,"disableRanking":false},"type":"PERIOD"}
```

So you'll end up doing something like:

```
UPDATE 
  foo 
SET 
  data = (
    SELECT 
      jsonb_set(
        (final.range_data):: jsonb, 
        '{type}', 
        to_jsonb(final.type)
      ) 
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          jsonb_set(
            jsonb '{}', '{rangeData}', fields.range_data
          ) AS range_data, 
          fields.type AS type 
        FROM 
          (
            SELECT 
              data.jsonb - 'type' AS range_data, 
              data.jsonb ->> 'type' AS type 
            FROM 
              (
                SELECT 
                  foo.data
              ) data
          ) fields
      ) final
  );
```

I haven't run the final `UPDATE` query, but I did run the naïve `SELECT` statement and it got me the output as expected.

Also, caveat, I'm new to SQL (and especially the jsonb stuff), so I'm sure there will be a more performant and/or more correct "jsonb-like" way to do this. Depends on your use-case (if it's a one-off migration, or if you need to do this during every live read, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made the choice of klin answer - short and efficient